# CASE WHEN used to define type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which shows me the structure of my organisation. I now want to define a type to each record by searching for a match in a few different tables.

I am setting up a webpage who shows you the OrgStructure. To simplify things, I want to colour code things based on the type for the record it is. If it is a division I want it to be green, units are red and so on. I thought of using CASE WHEN and LEFT JOIN with the different tables to "find a match" and then set the type. Any thought and ideas? In the code below you see my starting point. This shows me the different records in the structure and what level it is on. But several different things can me at the same level, therefore I want to define the type as well.

```
SELECT ID
        ,BelongTo_ID
        ,Name
        ,IdPath
        ,LEN(IdPath) - LEN(REPLACE(IdPath, '/', '')) AS Level
        ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.atbl_Common_Orgstructure WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE BelongTo_ID = OS.ID) 
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsEndpoint
FROM dbo.atbl_Common_Orgstructure OS WITH(NOLOCK)
```

I have a working view with the org structure in it, but I now want to set the type. I want to set the type based on what table the record is found. If it is found in the Divisions table then set the type to 1, is it found in the units table then set the type to 2 and so on.

Sample records:

[image: Sample Records]

Comment: Please provide us the sample input and output data

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN and CASE/WHEN as below-

```
SELECT ID
,BelongTo_ID
,Name
,IdPath
,LEN(IdPath) - LEN(REPLACE(IdPath, '/', '')) AS Level
,CASE 
    WHEN  A.BelongTo_ID IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Red'
    WHEN  B.<related column> IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Green'
    WHEN  C.<related column> IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Blue'
    ELSE 1 
END AS IsEndpoint
FROM dbo.atbl_Common_Orgstructure OS WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT BelongTo_ID FROM dbo.atbl_Common_Orgstructure WITH(NOLOCK)
) A ON OS.ID  =  A.BelongTo_ID

LEFT JOIN (
    ...
) B ON OS.ID  =  B.<related column>

LEFT JOIN (
    ...
) C ON OS.ID  =  C.<related column>
```

Comment: But this doesn't make it set the type based on what kind of record it is? As said above, I want it to set the type based on what table it finds a match in, say for example one of the table is named atbl_Common_Divisions and the other atbl_Common_Units.

Comment: You can add more tables by LEFT JOIN as I joined atbl_Common_Orgstructure and then add more WHEN (Per Table) in the CASE statement and set Type accordingly. I have updated the script for your clarification/idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the record will be only once in one of the tables....

```
;WITH cte_Common_Types AS (
    SELECT 'Division' AS TypeName, 'Green' AS TypeColor, ID
    FROM atbl_Common_Divisions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Unit' AS TypeName, 'Red' AS TypeColor, ID
    FROM atbl_Common_Units
)
SELECT 
    ID
    ,BelongTo_ID
    ,Name
    ,IdPath
    ,LEN(IdPath) - LEN(REPLACE(IdPath, '/', '')) AS Level
    ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.atbl_Common_Orgstructure WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE BelongTo_ID = OS.ID) 
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsEndpoint
    ,TypeName
    ,TypeColor
FROM dbo.atbl_Common_Orgstructure OS WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN cte_Common_Types CT ON OS.ID = CT.ID
```